# i dont understand docker volumes for DBs

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

in the last couple of days, i started digging into docker, i learned how to build an image how to to run a container from that image, and also learned about docker-compose and how to manage multiple containers, and then i wanted to test my knowledge and i created a simple nodejs with a mysql app, then when im in the middle of creating, i read something about volumes and it must be used with databases to persist the data.

**so what i dont understand is:** lets say i deployed the image and run the docker-compose file in a digitalocean server, what is gonna be the local volume for a mysql database, and if im running the mysql inside a container, why will i need a local mysql in the server itself, i hope you understood what my problem is.

i dont know if im understanding volumes right, can anyone explain to me volumes in production level how it works exactly when i deploy a nodejs + mysql db to a live server, how to persist the db data.

Comment: Please take a look at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql and read the section "Where to Store Data". They already answered to your question.

Short answer you can just use volume that mapped to host folder. That is it. Docker-compose can do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application run it will perform some operation like insertion, deletions, alterations, etc. When MySQL container goes down. It will delete the whole data. So, all the data that we need for future. We put in volume. Volumes are nothing just a directory in the host machine.

Next time when we start the container it will  automatically pick the data form that particular location. Docker just map the volume to container. If you change anything in volume it will reflect inside container as well.

```
version '3'
volumes:
  web_data:
    name: web

services:
  app:
   image: nginx:alpine
   Ports:
    - 80:80
   volumes:
    - web_data:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
```

Comment: Thanks, its clear now, i thought that i need to point to the mysql data folder in the host machine, stupid hhh

Comment: Exactly, you just need to make a volume to persist MySQL data.